# Assessment of a single predictive model

Tags: predictive-models, validation

I am facing a situation where I need to assess the predictive ability of a single (regression) model. I do not need to compare its performance with some other model, I just need to show that it predicts well or not. I have the Mean Square Error and Mean Absolute error for both on the training set and a separate test set. I also have the actual predictions so I can do some comparisons of the RMSE values with the mean predictions (or something similar) if needed. I understand that this probably depends also on the domain and how large an acceptable error is, but I cannot find any reference that discusses this topic in any level, every discussion on model assessment refers to comparison of different models.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Explain why you are using data splitting.  This is typically very unstable and inefficient unless $N>20000$.  To your question I would consider the two measures you listed, plus $R^{2}$, rank correlation between $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$, and a high-resolution nonparametric calibration curve.

Comment: Frank, thanks for the comment on the data splitting and the suggestions. My question still remains, how to evaluate the performance on the model, having the MSE and MAE available. How can we tell if the values are too high or low enough?

Comment: Except for the calibration curve, it's all relative and related to the intended use.  You can also consider directed goodness of fit tests (e.g., linearity, additivity).

Comment: Frank, I am interested in your comment about the problems with data splitting. Could you please point out some references to me? Thanks.

Comment: I go into this in detail in my book Regression Modeling Strategies and its course notes found online at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/CourseBios330 .  I got interested in that when data splitting was too noisy on a 17,000 patient dataset with a 0.3 event probability.